# GCC toolchain for LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, configure, rhel

I am running on an RHEL 6.x box, which of course has GCC 4.4 installed.  I wish to have LLVM running on this machine.  In order to do so, I must compile it from source.  In order to do *that*, I need a more modern version of GCC.

So, following [the instructions](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#requirements), I have built GCC 4.8.2:

```
[snip]
% $PWD/../gcc-4.8.2/configure --prefix=$HOME/toolchains --enable-languages=c,c++
% make -j$(nproc)
% make install
```

I'm logged in as root, so `$HOME/toolchains` resolves to `/root/toolchains`.

After satisfying prerequisites for LLVM, I'm ready to configure and build LLVM.

```
root@dev06 /root/llvm-build # ~/llvm/configure --enable-optimized --prefix=$HOME/toolchains/ --with-gcc-toolchain=/root/toolchains/
checking for clang... no
[snip]
checking target architecture... x86_64
checking whether GCC is new enough... no
configure: error:
The selected GCC C++ compiler is not new enough to build LLVM. Please upgrade
to GCC 4.7. You may pass --disable-compiler-version-checks to configure to
bypass these sanity checks.
root@dev06 /root/llvm-build #
```

`configure` thinks I'm using GCC 4.4 still, even though I passed `--with-gcc-toolchain=/root/toolchains/` to configure<sup>1</sup>.  Let's make sure that I installed 4.8.2 properly.

```
root@dev06 /root/llvm-build # $HOME/toolchains/bin/g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How do I convince `configure` to use the GCC I have at `/root/toolchains`?

---

<sup>1</sup>:  I have tried a number of variations of the path I specify in `--with-gcc-toolchain`, inclding `/root/toolchain/bin`, `/root/toolchain/bin/g++`, etc.

Comment: `$HOME/toolchains/bin/g++ --version` gives you 4.8.2 does not mean that the system sees this installation. Simple `g++ --version` should result in 4.8.2. I think you have already tried adding the install path to PATH variable, or not ? If yes, is the order correct?

Comment: @mishr:  But I specified `--with-gcc-toolchain=/root/toolchains/` on `configure`'s command line?

Comment: Note to readers:  Doing `export PATH=/root/toolchains/bin/:$PATH` *did* allow me to run `configure` cleanly, but I'd rather not do this everywhere, and it seems to imply that `--with-gcc-toolchain` doesn't do what I thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have discovered, the proper way to resolve this is by adding your custom toolchain to `PATH`. This is not a systemwide change, and is limited to your shell session. Alternatively, you can configure with:

```
../llvm/configure CXX=$HOME/toolchains/bin/g++
```

and similar options documented in `configure`'s `--help` output.

The option `--with-gcc-toolchain` only tells the built Clang where to look for a C++ standard library and headers, it has nothing to do with the LLVM/Clang build process. I strongly suggest to also build and install libc++ and libc++abi and use those with your new Clang instead.

Comment: Aha, I see.  `--with-gcc-toolchain` did *not* do what I thought it did.  Am I correct in assuming that even if I do `export` the path, I still need to specifiy the `with-gcc-toolchain` option?

Comment: @John As far as I understand, using that option will hardcode the libstdc++ paths from your GCC 4.8.2 install into the Clang binary, which means it can use that C++ library without extra options. So yes, I think that will be useful. To prevent this kind of trouble, I suggest using libc++ instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'll read through the docs again so that I can understand it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The LLVM project no longer supports building with configure & make.

I specified c, c++ and fortran compiler in the variables CC, CXX and FC.

```
export CC=/path/to/gcc
export CXX=/path/to/g++
export FC=/path/to/gfortran

cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/clang ../llvm-4.0.0
make
make install
```